# Setting a proxy in PowerShell on for the PowerShell WebClient?

Tags: powershell, networking, proxy

I am developing a PowerShell script that uses HTTP to access REST services. For debugging purposes I want to redirect all HTTP traffic created by that script through a local proxy (Fiddler).

What I don't want to is to set Fiddler as system wide proxy in IE/ Windows internet settings as this would redirect the traffic of my whole system through Fiddler (especially because Fiddler decrypts SSL/TLS traffic).

How do I set a proxy that affects only one WebClient instance or only the PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`WebProxy` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2tt59d8(v=vs.110).aspx) and instantiate it with the address to Fiddler (listens on port 8888 by default):

```
$FiddlerWP = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy "http://127.0.0.1:8888"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Proxy = $FiddlerWP

# This request will now get proxied through Fiddler
$WebClient.DownloadString("https://test.site.example")
```